# After 2nd render page got disappears after a flash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I am building react app using express js, axios, and Mongo DB. When I navigate from the home page to the detailed page (by clicking overlay) , react renders the detailed page twice and after 2nd time page disappears in a flash. Here are the pages.

Home page

```
const Post = ({ post, setCurrentId }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile"));

    const postDetails = (id) => {
        navigate(`posts/${id}`);
    };

    const deletePostHandler = () => {
        if (post.creator === user.id || post.creator === user.sub) {
            dispatch(deletePost(post._id));
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="post" key={post.id}>
            <div className="user-details">
                <img src={post.selectedFile} alt="" title={post.title} />
                <div className="overlay" onClick={() => postDetails(post._id)}></div> // here is the link to detailed page passing id to retrive specific details 
                <div className="top-left">
                    <span className="user-name">{post.name}</span>
                    <span className="time">{moment(post.createdAt).fromNow()}</span>
                </div>
                <button className="edit-button" onClick={() => setCurrentId(post._id)}>
                    <MoreHorizIcon></MoreHorizIcon>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className="details">
                <span className="tags">
                    {post.tags[0].split(",").map((tag) => "#" + tag.trim() + " ")}
                </span>
                <span className="title">{post.title}</span>
                <span className="message">{post.message}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="button-container">
                <button
                    className="like-button"
                    onClick={() => dispatch(likePost(post._id))}
                >
                    <ThumbUpIcon className="thumbUpIcon"></ThumbUpIcon>
                    {/* <ThumbUpOffAltIcon></ThumbUpOffAltIcon> */}

                    <span>
                        {post.likes.length > 1
                            ? `Likes ${post.likes.length}`
                            : `Like ${post.likes.length}`}
                    </span>
                </button>
                <button className="delete-button" onClick={deletePostHandler}>
                    <DeleteIcon></DeleteIcon>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Post;
```

Detailed page

```
const PostDetails = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { id } = useParams();
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getPost(id));
    }, []);
    const { post } = useSelector((state) => state.posts);

    if (!post) return null;

    return (
        <div className="post-detail-container">
            <div className="post-details">
                <div className="title">{post.title}</div>
                <div className="tags">
                    {post.tags[0].split(",").map((tag) => "#" + tag.trim() + " ")}
                </div>
                <p readOnly className="message">
                    {post.message}
                </p>
                <div className="createdBy">Created by: {post.name}</div>
                <div className="createdBy">{moment(post.createdAt).fromNow()}</div>
            </div>
            <img
                className="post-image"
                src={post.selectedFile}
                alt=""
                title={post.title}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

postReducer

```
import { POST_ACTION_TYPES } from "../../action/post/postActionTypes";

export const postReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    //state always will be posts
    switch (action.type) {
        case POST_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL:
            return action.payload;
        case POST_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_POST:
            return { ...state, post: action.payload };
        case POST_ACTION_TYPES.CREATE:
            return [...state, action.payload];
        case POST_ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE:
        case POST_ACTION_TYPES.LIKE:
            return state.map((post) =>
                post._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : post
            );
        case POST_ACTION_TYPES.DELETE:
            return state.filter((post) => post._id !== action.payload);
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Please explain why is that and help me to fix it.

Comment: Please provide a sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the logs?
Check the browser console for any errors, it may be that `post` is an array so you've to check if the array is empty by `array.length < 1 ? return null : return (<Component/>)` or you can use lodash `_. isEmpty()` . An empty array is a truthy value in javascript so `if(!post)` will return `false`